# Is the topological boundary of a set equal to the boundary of its closure or of its interior?

Tags: general-topology

Can you give me counter examples?

1-) Boundary of the set $S$ is the same as the boundary of the closure of $S$. I couldn't find a counterexample which would make this statement false, all my examples support this statement.

2-) Boundary of the set $S$ is the same as the boundary of the interior of $S$. What is meant by the boundary of the interior of $S$?. If $S$ is an open set then $S$ would be equal to its interior. Then this statement is the same as the 1st one.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the definition of the boundary? In fact, for most common sets in topological spaces the boundary and the closure will be very different. Indeed, an open set will never be a counterexample to the second statement. So try finding a set that is "very far from closed".

Comment: @MeesdeVries He isn't comparing the boundary of S to the closure of S. He is comparing the boundary of S to the boundary of the closure of S.

Comment: 2.) Consider instead a closed set S. The interior of this set isn't the same as the set itself. For example set $[0,1]$ is closed, it's interior is $(0,1)$ and the boundary exists of the points $\{0,1\}$. What is the boundary of the interior - $(0,1)$?

Comment: @PiotrBenedysiuk, my bad, I read the question wrong. But your example is also bad -- as a subset of $\mathbb R$ (or just of $[0,1]$), the boundary of $(0,1)$ is also $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: As a simple example, consider $A = \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$. Now, we know that $\partial A = [0,1]$ and $\overline{A} = [0,1]$ but $\partial \overline{A} = \emptyset$.

Comment: @gtoques In you example, since this should be in $\mathbb R$ (otherwise the closure and boundary is also wrong) the boundary is $\partial \overline{A} = \{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 4):

Remember that $\partial S = \overline S \cap \overline C_S$, where $C_S$ is the complementary of $S$. Let $S = \Bbb Q$ with the usual topology induced from $\Bbb R$. Let $\Bbb I = C_ {\Bbb Q}$, the irrational numbers.

1) On the one hand we have

$$\partial S = \overline {\Bbb Q} \cap \overline {\Bbb I} = \Bbb R \cap \Bbb R = \Bbb R .$$

On the other hand, since $\overline S = \overline {\Bbb Q} = \Bbb R$, we have that

$$\partial \overline S = \partial \Bbb R = \overline {\Bbb R} \cap \overline {C_{\Bbb R}} = \overline {\Bbb R} \cap \overline \emptyset = \Bbb R \cap \emptyset = \emptyset ,$$

which shows that $\partial S \ne \partial \overline S$.

2) We have that $\mathring S = \mathring {\Bbb Q} = \emptyset$, therefore

$$\partial \mathring S = \partial \emptyset = \overline \emptyset \cap \overline {C_\emptyset} = \emptyset \cap \overline {\Bbb R} = \emptyset \cap \Bbb R = \emptyset .$$

Since we had already obtained $\partial S = \Bbb R$, we see that $\partial S \ne \partial \mathring S$.

Comment: Or if you let $T=(0,1)\cap \mathbb Q ,$  then the boundaries of $T, $ $ \bar T, $  and  int($T)$ are 3 different sets.

Comment: Does the situation change, when $S$ is closed, i.e. can we then show that $\partial S^\circ=\partial S$?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: No, what you say is not true. Think of a single point in $\{ 0 \} \subset \mathbb R$: it is closed, but its interior is $\emptyset$, so $\partial \{0\} ^\circ = \emptyset$, while in fact $\partial \{0\} = \{0\}$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm actualy not interested in that generality, but in a special case: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3812514/47771. Maybe you can take a look.